# My facebook account disabled, what happens to my pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

My Facebook account is disabled. I had many pages that I was only administrator of. The pages are still working having no admins, how can I get my pages back?

I [asked Facebook help community](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=136390613365609) but got no answer

Comment: Your account is disabled by Facebook or you have disabled your account?

Answer (score 3):

If **you** *disabled* your Facebook account, you are still in control of logging back into it and resume all functions. Once you disable and log back in, it becomes undisabled.

Now, if **Facebook**, themselves, disabled your account, you have no abilities to control your account and/or pages. Your account and pages are under *their* control, until Facebook grants you access.   Unfortunately, there is no seperate log-in for your pages.

Comment: This is not an answer, this is a comment - facebook disabled my account - how would facebook grant me the access - are you making a guess please?

Comment: So what can I do in this case? is there any appeal form to get back my pages? that would be better answer

Comment: @Prakash: Since you said my answer is not an answer, I can no longer help you with your situation. Ive tried to help you and you said I was wrong. Good luck.

Comment: :) very well, i'll wait for somebody else, because yes, your answer didn't help!

Comment: Wonderful, as I've said before...Good Luck :)